# changing orientation workflow

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

if I have a long running Task (like an AsyncTask, or even a Thread that posts the result back to the main thread by using the MainLooper and handlers)
is it possible that the running tasks result (executed on the main thread) will be executed while the orientation change (from landscape to portrait or vice versa) is not fully finished?

For instance, is the following scenario possible:

1. I start an Activity
2. The long running task will start
3. I change the activity from portrait to landscape
4. Old activity will be destroyed
5. **long running task result will be executed (in example AsyncTask.onPostExecute(); )**
6. New Activity will be instanciated  in landscape (caused by orientation changes

So my question is:

Can I take it for granted, that orientation changes will execute destory of portrait activity and recreation of landscape activity on the main thread without executing onPostExecute() between them?

Will the workflow be always like this:

1. I start an Activity
2. The long running task will start
3. I change the activity from portrait to landscape
4. Old (portrait) activity will be destroyed
5. New Activity will be instanciated  in landscape (caused by orientation changes)
6. **long running task result will be executed (in example AsyncTask.onPostExecute(); )**

or like this

1. I start an Activity
2. The long running task will start
3. **long running task result will be executed (in example AsyncTask.onPostExecute(); )**
4. I change the activity from portrait to landscape
5. Old (portrait) activity will be destroyed
6. New Activity will be instanciated  in landscape (caused by orientation changes)

but never like this:

1. Old (portrait) activity will be destroyed
2. **long running task result will be executed (in example AsyncTask.onPostExecute(); )**
3. New Activity will be instanciated  in landscape (caused by orientation changes)

Im asking because Im not sure if destruction and recreation of the activity will be executed in a single run on the MainLooper ... It's hard to test it, beacause its timeing is hard to reproduce. So expert knowledge would be great at this point ... It could also be implemented with a Fragment (i.e. with setRetainInstanceState) instead of an Activity

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Fragment#setRetainInstanceState(boolean)` then you can allow a fragment to keep the AsyncTask alive even after Activity recreation.  This is considered the best way to do this, with the last resort option being to set `configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest file.

Comment: Yes i know, but that was not my question. All I want to know is if its possible that the tasks result will be executed while portrait was destroyed but landscape is has not been recreated yet.

Comment: No, it's not possible but only if you use one of the methods I describe, i.e. by not killing the background thread's context.  If you just host the task in an Activity without any measures to ensure it does not lose its context, then the problem will occur.  The task's result won't even execute if it finishes after the Activity has been recreated, you'll get an exception because it's callback interface no longer exists.